# Может ли размер указателя меняться в зависимости от типа объекта, на который он указывает?

Tags: c, указатели

Я сейчас читаю «[A Tutorial on Pointers and Arrays in C](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm)» и дошел до этого абзаца в конце [второй главы](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/ch2x.htm):

> Also we have learned that on different systems the size of a pointer
>   can vary. As it turns out it is also possible that the size of a
>   pointer can vary depending on the data type of the object to which it
>   points. Thus, as with integers where you can run into trouble
>   attempting to assign a long integer to a variable of type short
>   integer, you can run into trouble attempting to assign the values of
>   pointers of various types to pointer variables of other types.

Перевод:

«*Также мы узнали, что на разных системах размер указателя может менятся. Оказывается, что размер указателя может менятся и в зависимости от типа данных объекта, на который он указывает. Таким образом, как и в случае с целыми числами, когда у вас могут возникнуть проблемы при попытке присвоить значение `long int` переменной типа `short int`, у вас могут возникнуть проблемы при присваивании значения указателя одного типа указателю другого типа*».

Я же всегда думал, что размер указателя зависит только от платформы (x32, x64).

Нашел [вот такой вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473935/can-the-size-of-pointers-vary-between-data-and-function-pointers) на enSO, где говорится, что размер указателя на *данные* и указателя на *функцию* могут быть разными. Я объясняю себе это так: размер секции кода меньше, чем размер секции данных или размера RAM, поэтому любой адрес в секции кода может поместится в 2-х байтной (к примеру) переменной, а адрес секции данных или RAM только в 4-х (тоже к примеру).

Итак, два вопроса:

1. Прав ли я на счет причины разницы между размером указателя на данные и на функцию?
2. Могут ли отличатся размеры указателя на разные типы данных, например `char *` и `int *`?

Comment: [Are all data pointers the same size in one platform for all data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241205)

Comment: @zed, спасибо за ссылку. Ответ на второй вопрос есть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Язык С требует чтобы внутренние представления и требования выравнивания указателей совпадали в следующих группах (в каждой группе - между собой)

1. Указатели `void *` и `char *`
2. Указатели на все struct-типы
3. Указатели на все union-типы
4. Указатели на совместимые типы

Во всех остальных случаях указатели могут иметь совершенно разное представление, в т.ч. отличающиеся размеры.

Т.е. да, формально указатели `char *` и `int *` могут иметь разный размер.

Причины, по которым может иметь смысл делать указатели разного размера включают

1. Разница в размере областей адресного пространства, в котором могут располагаться указуемые сущности. Например, как вы заметили, разница в размере областей кода и данных может обуславливать разницу в размерах указателей на данные и указателей на функции
2. Разница в требованиях выравнивания типа. Например, если некоторый экзотический тип требует выравнивания на границу 256 байт, то ему фактически "не нужен" последний байт в полном указателе.

На практике обычно эта овчинка стоит выделки только на платформах с сегментной организацией памяти, где зачастую реализуют деление на "far" и "near" указатели.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
     int *a;
     char *b;
     double ***d;
     void (*f)(int*,int**);
     printf("int pointer - %d\n",sizeof(a));  //4
     printf("char pointer - %d\n",sizeof(b));//4
     printf("double double pointer - %d\n",sizeof(d));//4
     printf("function pointer - %d\n",sizeof(f));//4
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: смотри все просто, (char *b) где b ето указатель к блоку памяти типу char.

Comment: Но давай посмотрим мы не на формальную сторону языка Си, а на практическую часть. Любой указатель это обычная переменная типа unsigned int, потому что мы в неё сохраняем адрес какой-то ячейке памяти. На 32 битной системе тип unsigned int займёт 4 байта, а на 64 битной системе 8 байта. Тип указателя определяет сколько байт будем читать, начиная с адресом который сохранен в указателе, еще тип указателя нужен для арифметических действия с указателями. Поэтому не важно какой тип указателя, главное помнит что это адрес и любой адрес это тип unsigned int (формально).

Comment: Есть и нестандартные системы где сектор кода и сектор данных в разных адресных таблицах, но это уже другая история.

Comment: Размер типа unsigned int никак не связан с разрядностью платформы. И хотя увидеть 8-байтовый unsigned int на 64-битной платформе было бы вполне естественно, в реальной жизни тип unsigned int обычно имеет размер 4 байта даже на 64-битных платформах. Поэтому не ясно, зачем вы приплели сюда unsigned int.

Comment: @CaptainOfHacks, вместо написания комментариев,дополняющих ответ, вы можете «править» свой ответ (под ним есть одноименная кнопка-ссылка).

Comment: @AnT я это для примера чтоб просто он понял без много вопросов. Я не стал объяснить про разных архитектур и методов организации программ в памяти, или про виртуальной памяти и физической.